# ThreadPool() too slow - can I speed it?

Tags: python, multithreading, rest, databricks

I have a function

```
def get_subclient_info(client_id: int)->list:
    subclient_url = "http://{0}/SearchSvc/CVWebService.svc/Subclient?clientId={1}".format(vault_url,client_id)
    
    subclient_info = {
            'client_id': None,
            'client_name': None,
            'subclient_id': None,
            'subclient_name': None,
            'application_id': None,
            'application_name': None,
            'instanceName': None,
            'subclient_backup_enabled': None
    }
    headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authtoken': '{0}'.format(access_token)
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", subclient_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    response_json = json.loads(response.text)
    #print(response_json)
    subclient_info_list = []
    sub_clients= response_json.get('subClientProperties',{})
    for s in sub_clients:
        sub_client_data={
            "client_id" : client_id,
            "client_name" : s["subClientEntity"]["clientName"],
            "subclient_id" : s["subClientEntity"]["subclientId"],
            "subclient_name" : s["subClientEntity"]["subclientName"],
            "application_id" : s["subClientEntity"]["applicationId"],
            "application_name" : s["subClientEntity"]["appName"],
            "subclient_backup_enabled" : get_subclient_backup_status(s["subClientEntity"]["subclientId"]),
            "instanceName"  : get_subclient_InstanceName(s["subClientEntity"]["subclientId"])
        }
       
        subclient_info_list.append(sub_client_data)
    return subclient_info_list
```

that is called by threadpool executor

```
import requests
import concurrent.futures

subclient_entities = {}
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:

    futures_sub = [executor.submit(get_subclient_info, client_id) for client_id in list_clientid]

    for client_id, future_s in zip(list_clientid, concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_sub)):
        result = future_s.result()
        subclient_entities[client_id] = result
```

Having 7000 clients, it takes more than 1 hour.
In beginning I was using normal for loops on databricks, After that I've switched to Thread Pool Executor and it seemed to go faster.
Now, I don't know if I can make my code faster and if thread pool executor is correct or I've found the limit of python.

What would you suggest ?

Switched from for loops to comprehension list and then to Thread Pool Executor.
I would expect to narrow it down to 30 minutes

Comment: Try adding some debug information such as timing of the HTTP GET request. Also, take a look at what os.cpu_count() reveals. You will have (at most) that value multiplied by 5 concurrent threads

Comment: First you need to figure out where you lose performance. Is it the network requests or the json parsing? My money is on the network but you have to verify. If it is the network and many requests go to the same host, consider [using sessions](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects). Even if not, requests has recommendations for [better alternatives to thread pools](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an extended comment (contains formatted code), not an answer.

---

Are you aware that `as_completed(futures_sub)` *changes the order* of the members of `futures_sub`? In fact, that's the *only* thing that it does. It lets you visit a list of `Future` objects in the order that they are completed instead of visiting them in the original order.

Try running this code example. Does the output match your expectation?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import concurrent.futures
import time

def get_subclient_info(client_id):
    time.sleep(client_id)
    return f"<info for client {client_id}>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_clientid = [3, 9, 4, 1, 5, 2]
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    futures_sub = [executor.submit(get_subclient_info, client_id) for client_id in list_clientid]
    for client_id, future_s in zip(list_clientid, concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_sub)):
        result = future_s.result()
        print(f"client_id={client_id}, result={future_s.result()}")
```